# I want to flash my my Skyrocket I-727. There's an issue, though: My USB conneciton isn't recognized on any computer

Tags: cyanogenmod, custom-roms, root-access, samsung

I got a Skyrocket my father no longer uses and there's a big problem with it: the Wifi doesn't work.  after some checking with buddies, discussions, and searching, I'vbe figured out it's a software issue.  I'd like to root, and then flash and install the latest stable release of CM 10.2 on the device.  All of this would have been done weeks ago, however, it seems that my device's USB port is either unreadable or corrupt.  Any computer I plug it in to the device is not properly recognized.  Hell, I would have used the CM Installer already.

So my main question is:
**I have a stock, non-root Skyrocket I-727. The Wifi does not work, nor does the USB connection.  Is there any way to put a custom ROM, or even another Stock-based ROM on this device using just the shirt on my back and a microSD?**

Comment: Try uninstalling all Samsung USB drivers, including the Kies program, rebooting the computer and then installing the drivers from here: http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SGH-I727MSAATT

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is head over to sammobile.com and download the latest firmware for your phone, then using Odin you can flash the new firmware.

If your driver issues are software related then this will work because Odin uses your phones "Download Mode" and that is a different driver all together, and if your truly stock and not rooted there is no way you could have changed it.

Samsung Kies will come with the needed driver for download mode to get that too if you don't already have it.

Also you can check out forum.xda-developers.com there is a lot of useful tools and guides there.

Another option if the Samsung Kies for skyrocket supports it is a firmware emergency recovery. It will install the latest firmware, and use download mode to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  Unfortunately, Nothing as far as your suggestions worked.  It still shows that the USB is unrecognized, and ODIN doesn't even recognize it in DL mode.  I'm guessing the problem is my device itself, because the cable itself recognizes other devices.